# Parity - scheduled TX on local time zone

Tags: parity, timestamp, browsers

Looks like the Parity Browser doesn't show the local time zone for a "send after Date & Time' functionality.

Questions:

1. What is the time zone for a scheduled TX on Parity?
2. If the scheduled time is based on local time zone - how is this time zone calculated? Local computer time or IP?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's your local computer's timezone.